# Can't get stderr with Paramiko

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

For some reasons, I have to use `mysql` over Paramiko.

I have this (simplified) snippet:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command("mysql stuff -e 'rename table foo to bar'")
print stdout.read()
print stderr.read()
```

But if table `foo` doesn't exist, I have no output (there is no `stdout` or `stdin` output).

But it is strange, because:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command("mysql stuff -e 'rename table foo to bar'")
if stderr.read()
    print "Error: %s" % stderr.read()
    print type(stderr.read())
```

Has this output:

```
Error:
<type 'str'>
```

Whereas the `mysql` error would normally be:

> ERROR 1017 (HY000) at line 1: Can't find file: './stuff/foo.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

I'd like to have this more verbose error output, but I can't have it. Why?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot read `stdin`. It's input, not output.

That's why you get *"File is not open for reading"*. It has nothing to do with your `mysql` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
if stderr.read()
    print "Error: %s" % stderr.read()
    print type(stderr.read())
```

The first call to `stderr.read()` makes subsequent calls to it return nothing.

Change it to something like:

```
for line in stderr:
    print "Error: %s" % line
```

Comment: `I'd like to have this more verbose error output, but I can't have it. Why?`. Because your code has already read output by the time you try to print it, as the answer above states. What question has not been answered?

Comment: OK, I see, the `if stderr.read()`. But note that the first code snippet does simple `print stdout.read()`. (note that it's not my code)

Comment: You need to wait for the command to finish before reading output, otherwise output will be empty. `eof()` or iteration on the stdout/stderr, again like the answer says, will work fine. For questions on code, show the code in question.